# enable and disable cell selection based on a value on custom ui-grid

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom ui-grid in our app and it is like below:

```
app.directive('stkGrid', ['$window', '$timeout', function($window, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,       
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            autoHeight: '=',
            selectionVariable: '=',
            onRowSelect: '&',
            onRowDeselect: '&',
            onRowsChanged: '&',
            selectAll: '@',
            canSelect: '@',
            columnDefs: '=',
            multiSelect: '@',
            noUnselect: '@'
        },
        controllerAs: 'parentCtrl',
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element) {
            var $attrs = $element[0].attributes;

            $scope.$watch('selectionVariable', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (!newValue || !newValue.length) {
                    //$scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows();
                }
            });

            function rowSelectionChanged(row) {
                // row selection logic
            };

            $scope.stkGridOptions = {
                data: 'data',
                enableRowSelection: ($scope.canSelect != 'false'),
                enableSelectAll: ($scope.selectAll == 'true'),
                multiSelect: ($scope.multiSelect == 'true'),
                noUnselect: (typeof $scope.noUnselect !== 'undefined'),
                enableFullRowSelection: true,
                selectionRowHeaderWidth: 0,
                rowHeight:25,
                onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
                    //register api logic
                },
                columnDefs: (!!$scope.columnDefs ? $scope.columnDefs : [])
            };

            this.addColumn=function(col) {
                if (!!$scope.columnDefs) {
                    return;
                }

                $scope.stkGridOptions.columnDefs.push(col);
            };

            $scope.$watchCollection("columnDefs", function(newColumnDefs) {
                if (!newColumnDefs) {
                    return;
                }

                $scope.stkGridOptions.columnDefs = newColumnDefs;
            });
        }],
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            // window resize logic
        },
        template: '<div ui-grid="stkGridOptions" ui-grid-selection></div><div ng-transclude></div>'
    };
}]).directive('stkCol', function() {
    return {
        require: '^^stkGrid',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
            field: '@',
            displayName: '@',
            width: '@',
            maxWidth: '@',
            minWidth: '@',
            cellFilter: '@',
            cellClass: '@',
            cellTemplate: '=',
            type: '@',
            formatter: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, stkGridCtrl) {
            stkGridCtrl.addColumn(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

This custom ui-grid has been defined in home.html:

```
<stk-grid id="batchDocumentGrid" data="batchCtrl.documents" auto-height="180" selection-variable="batchCtrl.selectedDocument" ng-dblclick="homeCtrl.viewDocument(homeCtrl.selectedDocument)">
    <stk-col display-name="Include" field="include" cell-template="homeCtrl.documentFieldTemplates['include']" width="128"></stk-col>
    <stk-col display-name="Filename" field="fileName" cell-template="homeCtrl.documentFieldTemplates['fileName']"></stk-col>
    <stk-col display-name="Document Type" field="typeAbbreviation" cell-template="homeCtrl.documentFieldTemplates['typeAbbreviation']"></stk-col>
    <stk-col display-name="Amount" field="documentAmount" cell-template="homeCtrl.documentFieldTemplates['documentAmount']" width="120"></stk-col>
</stk-grid>
```

Column definitions are defined in home.js:

```
vm.documentFieldTemplates = {
        'include': '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.include" />',
        'fileName': '<span ng-class="{inactive: !row.entity.include}">{{row.entity.fileName}}</span>',
        'typeAbbreviation': '<select class="form-control" ng-options="docType.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ABBREVIATION as docType.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ABBREVIATION for docType in grid.appScope.$parent.homeCtrl.docTypes" ng-model="row.entity.typeAbbreviation" ng-disabled="!row.entity.include" ng-change="grid.appScope.$parent.homeCtrl.docTypeChanged(row.entity.typeAbbreviation)"><option value="">&lt;Select Document Type&gt;</option></select>',
        'documentAmount': '<input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.documentAmount" ng-disabled="!row.entity.include || !grid.appScope.$parent.homeCtrl.isDocTypeSomething"/>'
    };
```

When document type changed, below method will define a boolean to enable or disable the amount column:

```
function docTypeChanged(typeAbbr) {
        if (typeAbbr == "SOMETHING") {
            vm.isDocTypeSomething = true;
        } else {
            vm.isDocTypeSomething = false;
        }
    }
```

But the issue here is, as this variable is defined at grid level scope or 
common for every row, when ever I change a document type it is changing for all rows. How to make this change for amount column to enable and disable for a particular row.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding change listener for typeAbbreviation column, adding a function to amount column ng-disabled property solved the issue.

```
vm.documentFieldTemplates = {
        'include': '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.include" />',
        'fileName': '<span ng-class="{inactive: !row.entity.include}">{{row.entity.fileName}}</span>',
        'typeAbbreviation': '<select class="form-control" ng-options="docType.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ABBREVIATION as docType.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ABBREVIATION for docType in grid.appScope.$parent.homeCtrl.docTypes" ng-model="row.entity.typeAbbreviation" ng-disabled="!row.entity.include"><option value="">&lt;Select Document Type&gt;</option></select>',
        'documentAmount': '<input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.documentAmount" ng-disabled="!row.entity.include || grid.appScope.$parent.homeCtrl.isDisabled(row.entity.typeAbbreviation)" />'
    };

function isDisabled(typeAbbr) {
        if(typeAbbr == "SOMETHING") {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```